# Why the generic method changed the parametrized type in an assignation?

Tags: java, generics

When writing a generic method to process data for a form, I came across with the following (as I see it) unexpedted behavior. Given the following code:

```
public class Test {
   public <T> void someGenericMethod(Integer a) {
      @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
      T t = (T) a;
      System.out.println(t);
      System.out.println(t.getClass());
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Test test = new Test();
      test.<BigDecimal>someGenericMethod(42);
   }  
}
```

AFAIK, the code above should generate a `ClassCastException` in the line `T t = (T) a` because the method call in main is setting the parametrized type to `BigDecimal` and casting from `Integer` to BigDecimal is not allowed, conversely to what I expected, the program executed well and printed the following:

```
42
class java.lang.Integer
```

In fact, if I add another parameter to the method signature (like `String b`) and make another assigment `T t2 = (T) b`, the program prints

```
42
class java.lang.String
```

Why the `t` variable changed it's type to `Integer` (is, by any chance, making some kind of promotion on the type T to Object)?

Any explanation on this behavior is welcome

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`(T) a` is an *unchecked cast*: due to [type erasure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html), the runtime has no way of knowing what type `T` is, so it can't actually check if `a` belongs to type `T`.

The compiler issues a warning when you do this; in your case, you've suppressed that warning by writing `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")`.

---

**Edited to add** (in response to a further question in the comments below):

If you want to check the cast, you can write this:

```
public class Test {
   public <T> void someGenericMethod(Class<T> clazz, Integer a) {
      T t = clazz.cast(a);
      System.out.println(t);
      System.out.println(t.getClass());
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Test test = new Test();
      // gives a ClassCastException at runtime:
      test.someGenericMethod(BigDecimal.class, 42);
   }
}
```

by passing in `clazz`, you allow the runtime to check the cast; and, what's more, you allow the compiler to infer `T` from the method arguments, so you don't have to write `test.<BigDecimal>someGenericMethod` anymore.

Of course, the code that calls the method can still circumvent this by using an unchecked cast:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   Test test = new Test();
   Class clazz = Object.class;
   test.someGenericMethod((Class<BigDecimal>) clazz, 42);
}
```

but then that's `main`'s fault, not `someGenericMethod`'s. :-)

Comment: Yes, is an unchecked cast, but why is not throwing a `ClassCastException` instead of changing the type of `T` to `Object`?

Comment: Because it's an unchecked cast. The runtime can't check the validity of the cast. If the runtime could check the cast, it would see that it's invalid, and throw a `ClassCastException`; but it can't, so it doesn't, and doesn't. I'm not sure why you expect otherwise.

Comment: Pretty much the _definition_ of an unchecked cast is that it can't check if a `ClassCastException` would be thrown if the full type information were known at runtime.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, didn't know unchecked cast implies that much

Comment: So, the `<BigDecimal>` thing in the `test.<BigDecimal>someGenericMethod` invocation is pretty useless if the method signature does not contains at least one `T` parameter?

Comment: @h3nr1x: Pretty much, yes. I've edited my answer to give something a bit more useful.

Answer (score 2):

When compiling, your code above basically becomes the following non-generic method:

```
public void someGenericMethod(Integer a) {
   Object t = a;
   System.out.println(t);
   System.out.println(t.getClass());
}
```

There is no cast. No exception.

Comment: Thanks, so the `<BigDecimal>` is useless if you don't add a parameter of type `T` in the method signature...

Answer (score 1):

You specify a type parameter in your method signature, but never use it.

I think you want something like this:

```
public class Test {
   public <T> void someGenericMethod(T someItem) {
      System.out.println(someItem);
      System.out.println(someItem.getClass());
   }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Test test = new Test();
    BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(42);

    test.someGenericMethod(42);    // Integer
    test.someGenericMethod("42");  // String
    test.someGenericMethod(42L);   // Long
    test.someGenericMethod(bd);    // BigDecimal
}
```

Note that there's no need to cast.

The parameter type is declared in the method signature and inferred from the parameter.

In your code you're parameterizing the method call (which I've never seen) and passing in an int.

It's kinda hard to understand what you're trying to do, since your example code does nothing.